# Socket Programming Java: How to receive multiple files from outputstream?

Tags: java, networking, serversocket

My server is sending several files to my client. However at the client side, it only receives the first file because I don't know how to iterate and get the second file.

The Server sends like this:

```
ListIterator iter = missingfiles.listIterator(); 
                    //missingfiles contain all the filenames to be sent
String filename;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    // System.out.println(iter.next());
    filename=(String) iter.next();
    File myFile = new File("src/ee4210/files/"+filename); 
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];  

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);  
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);  
    //bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);  

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);     
    dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);  

    OutputStream os = _socket.getOutputStream();  

    //Sending file name and file size to the server  
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);     
    dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());     
    dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);     
    dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);     
    dos.flush(); 
}
```

The client receives like this: (It will only receive the first file and I don't know how to make it loop to receive the next file)

```
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
int filecount = 0;
InputStream in;
try {
    in = _socket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
        String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                               "src/ee4210/files/"+ fileName);
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (size > 0
                && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
                        (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: "I don't know how to make it loop to receive the next file" - uh... just put a `while` around  the lines that read the file? (Starting with `String fileName = ...` and ending before the `catch (...)` block. And maybe add a sentinel value from the client that tells you it's done sending files, or have it send the number of files it will send at the start of the transmission, or just close the connection and have the `while` loop continue until that happens.

Comment: And seeing as you're using `DataOutputStream` at the server, why aren't you reading the data with `DataInputStream` at the client? I'm guessing what you're actually reading might end up garbled if `DOS` doesn't really output arrays as straightforwardly as you assume.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it. Still new to Java. What should I do now?

Comment: Read tutorials on networking and serialisation / learn to walk before you run? Try to implement a simpler multiple-message protocol first, then worry about  transferring complex objects. SO isn't the right place for conceptual walkthroughs.

Answer (score 0):

> How to receive multiple files from outputstream?

The obvious answer is 'one at a time, with extra information to tell you where one stops and another starts'. The most usual technique is to send the file size ahead of the file, e.g. as a long via `DataOutputStream.writeLong()`, and at the receiver change your read loop to stop after exactly that many bytes, close the output file, and continue the outer loop that reads the next long or end-of-stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
I've used a lazy method to check that the end of all 3 files have been received.

```
    int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;
    int filecount = 0;
    InputStream in;
    try 
    {
        in = _socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);

        while(true) 
        {
            String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
            // will throw an EOFException when the end of file is reached. Exit loop then.

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("src/ee4210/files/"+ fileName);
            long size = clientData.readLong();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (size > 0
                    && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
                            (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) 
            {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                size -= bytesRead;
            }
            output.close();
        }

    } 
    catch (EOFException e)
    {
        // means we have read all the files
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```